# How to avoid flicker while refreshing iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

*First of all, even if my question is about how to refresh `<iframe>`'s without flickering, any other suggestions that would solve my problem will be welcome.*

*Problem:* I have a server that publishes a "main" html page. Meanwhile, it takes pictures (say, one per second) and saves them on the HDD. I want the picture to be displayed on the web page and be refreshed.

*Solution found:* I use a `<iframe></iframe>` scope where I put another page that contains only the image. Then this second page is refreshed periodically. So, the entire page is not refreshed, only the image frame. The problem is that this solution suffers from a flickering that occurs each time it is refreshed.

Here is the code of the main page (a little compacted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Blabla</title></head>
<body bgcolor="#404040"><h1>WELCOME!...</h1><hr>
<table border="0"><tr height="480"><td width="640">

<!-- RIGHT HERE! -->
<iframe src="image.html" width="640" height="480" frameborder="0"></iframe>

</td></tr></table>
</body></html>
```

and the second web page is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function f( t )
{
    setTimeout( "location.reload( true );", t );
}
-->
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#000000" onload="JavaScript:f( 1000 );">
<img src="../images/myimage.png" alt="Erreur" height="100%" width="100%"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm a beginner in JavaScript, so I don't pretend this piece of code is good, even passable. Feel free to give me some advice.

Now, is it possible to reload without flickering? I read that the flickers occur while the page is not entirely loaded. I also read about *hidden* frames switched on and off during load time, etc. But I cannot find a good solution.

Also, I know that some technologies like AJAX exist but I don't know a lot more about them. Feel free to suggest me to use them if it is necessary, I can learn quickly...

---

**EDIT 1:** Most Android browsers don't support relative image size like in my example. Use absolute pixel values in place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reloading an iframe will always flicker. But you don't need ajax for this either, just a timer and a trick to avoid caching:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Blabla</title></head>
<body bgcolor="#404040"><h1>WELCOME!...</h1><hr>
<table border="0"><tr height="480"><td width="640">

<div>
    <img id="theimg" src="../images/myimage.png" alt="Erreur" height="100%" width="100%"/>
</div>

</td></tr></table>

<script type="text/javascript">
var theimg = document.getElementById("theimg");
var theurl = "../images/myimage.png";
setInterval(function() {
    theimg.src = theurl + '?t=' + new Date().getTime();
}, 1000);
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly. For an educational purpose only, I suppose the time you add to the URL is to avoid reusing cached image rather than reloading the new one having the same name?

Comment: For everybody's info, most Android browsers **don't support '%' as <img> size...** Took a little while to solve but if you want to show it on a tablet/phone, use absolute pixel units.

Comment: @bbfavaretto Your ans is perfect but i think  this statement **Reloading an iframe will always flicker** is wrong. This issue is resolved. [Bugzilla Mozilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=238714). Can you provide us another ans.